# Double Slash Assignment division in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and found a function that checks to see if an array of arguments can be made equal by only multiplying the number by 2.  However, there is some notation that I do not understand.

Function:

```
def isEqual(a,n): # a is an arrary, n is the length of array
for i in range(0,n):
    while a[i]%2==0: 
        a[i]//=2 # this is the part I do not understand
    print(a[i])
    if a[i] != a[0]:  
        return print("False")

# Otherwise, all elements equal, return true    
return print("True")
```

When I step through the function I see that it replaces the `a[i]` number by `a[i]//2`, but I do not understand why you would write `//` *equals to* *number*

I understand the `//` is "floor" division, but not why someone would write `a[i]//=2`.  I would have thought to write it as `a[i]=a[i]//2`. I can only assume these are the same things, I just never saw it written this way.

Test code:

```
a = [50, 4, 2]
n = len(a)  

isEqual(a, n)
```

Comment: It's a shorthand way of doing your version, of `a[i]=a[i]//2` that's all.

Comment: There's a [whole family](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators#assignment) of these assignment operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have came across operations that also assign value. Think

```py
a += 1    # same as: a = a + 1
```

This is exactly the same. It integer divides and assigns the value. Probably better understood with proper spacing:

```py
a //= 2    # same as: a = a // 2
```